# Maximising log likelihood for two parameters

Tags: python, optimization, differential-equations, log-likelihood

I have two parameters I'd like to maximise the log likelihood for and get the optimal parameter values. The code here calculates an ODE system, from which I will use two trajectories as x and y data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math


# Total population, N.
N = 1
# Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
I0, R0 = 0.001, 0
# Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
U0 = N - I0 - R0
J0 = I0
Lf0, Ls0 = 0, 0
# Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
beta, gamma = 8, 0.4
mu, muTB, sigma, rho = 1/80, 1/6, 1/6, 0.03
u, v, w = 0.88, 0.083, 0.0006
t = np.linspace(0, 500, 500+1)

# The SIR model differential equations.
def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma, mu, muTB, sigma, rho, u, v, w):
    U, Lf, Ls, I, R, cInc = y
    b = (mu * (U + Lf + Ls + R)) + (muTB * I)
    lamda = beta * I
    clamda = 0.2 * lamda
    dU = b - ((lamda + mu) * U)
    dLf = (lamda*U) + ((clamda)*(Ls + R)) - ((u + v + mu) * Lf)
    dLs = (u * Lf) - ((w + clamda + mu) * Ls)
    dI = w*Ls + v*Lf - ((gamma + muTB + sigma) * I) + (rho * R)
    dR = ((gamma + sigma) * I) - ((rho + clamda + mu) * R)
    cI = w*Ls + v*Lf + (rho * R)
    return dU, dLf, dLs, dI, dR, cI


# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
solve = odeint(deriv, (U0, Lf0, Ls0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma, mu, muTB, sigma, rho, u, v, w))
U, Lf, Ls, I, R, cInc = solve.T
```

My next function simply calculates the log likelihood when values for beta and gamma are passed in, which is what I'm trying to optimise

```
def loglik(beta, gamma):
    
    solve = odeint(deriv, (U0, Lf0, Ls0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma, mu, muTB, sigma, rho, u, v, w))
    U, Lf, Ls, I, R, cInc = solve.T #get trajectories

    muPrev, sigmaPrev = I[-1]*100000, 40 #I (prevalence)
    muInc, sigmaInc = (cInc[1:] - cInc[:-1])[-1]*100000, 30 #cInc (incidence)
    n = 10000
    
    # logPrev = np.random.lognormal(np.log((muPrev**2) / (muPrev**2 + sigmaPrev**2)**0.5), (np.log(1 + (sigmaPrev**2 / muPrev**2)))**0.5, n) #lognormal
    # logInc = np.random.lognormal(np.log((muInc**2) / (muInc**2 + sigmaInc**2)**0.5), (np.log(1 + (sigmaInc**2 / muInc**2)))**0.5, n) #lognormal
    
    xPrev = I[-1]*100000 #value of x in formula for log of pdf
    xInc = (cInc[1:] - cInc[:-1])[-1]*100000 #value of x in formula for log of pdf
    
    logmuPrev = np.log((muPrev**2) / (muPrev**2 + sigmaPrev**2)**0.5) #lognormal params
    logsdPrev = (np.log(1 + (sigmaPrev**2 / muPrev**2)))**0.5
    
    logmuInc = np.log((muInc**2) / (muInc**2 + sigmaInc**2)**0.5)#lognormal params
    logsdInc = (np.log(1 + (sigmaInc**2 / muInc**2)))**0.5
    
    L_prev = -0.5*((np.log(xPrev) - logmuPrev) / logsdPrev)**2 - np.log(xPrev * logsdPrev * (2*math.pi)**0.5) #log of pdf for prev and inc
    L_inc = -0.5*((np.log(xInc) - logmuInc) / logsdInc)**2 - np.log(xInc * logsdInc * (2*math.pi)**0.5)
    
    logsum = L_prev + L_inc #summing logs
    np.exp(logsum) #exp for likelihood
    return np.exp(logsum)
```

Finally, I try to optimise, but my arrays have different shapes so I cannot optimise this. How do I fix this so I can correctly maximise the log likelihood?

```
x = I[:-1]
y = cInc[1:] - cInc[:-1]
lik_model = minimize(loglik, 8, 0.4, method='L-BFGS-B')
```

----edit----

I have managed to get the minimise to run, but it is just returning the 8 and 0.4 values I fed into it?

results:

```
      fun: 0.00013295432301190784
 hess_inv: <2x2 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([-5.75331835e-08,  6.87479045e-07])
  message: 'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
     nfev: 3
      nit: 0
     njev: 1
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([8. , 0.4])
```

Comment: seems you provide initial parameters in wrong way, 8 and 0.4 should be a single argument `x0` in minimize

Comment: @dankal444 so redfined it to `x0 = [8, 0.4]` and then 
`lik_model = minimize(loglik, x0, method='L-BFGS-B')` but this still returns the initial guesses

Comment: try to debug and check if everything goes ok. Check how many times your loglik function is run, with which parameters, are results sane (not Inf/NaN), etc.

Comment: @dankal444 in my new edit ive shown the output